# Suppress RZ10012 analyser in blazor project

Tags: .net, razor, blazor, roslyn, omnisharp

In my blazor project, I get hundreds of `RZ10012` warnings:

> Found markup element with unexpected name 'Foo'. If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace.(RZ10012)

This is a known bug (going back for years). It's been reported dozens of times here on SO and on GitHub. There are no fixes or workarounds that work consistently.

It's impossible to be productive when the entire editor shows squigglies. Since the app itself works, I want to suppress that analyser rule.

So I added this to an `.editorconfig` in the project's root:

```ini
[*.razor]
dotnet_diagnostic.RZ10012.severity = none
```

That doesn't help. I also tried a `.globalconfig` file.

How can I suppress it?

(I'm using .net6 and vscode)

Answer (score 3):

The error comes from a generated file that does not live in a place in the same project or the same/child folder of `editorconfig`, so it doesn't affect it.

See https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/55921

You can try other ways like using a `NoWarn` tag in your project file:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <NoWarn>10012</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

(It seems to take only the numeric part of the warning)

If you have a shared file, you might also be able to drop something like this there:

```
@{
   #pragma warning disable RZ10012
}
```

But as per my knowledge the only suitable would have been the imports one, which doesn't allow such block. I thought I'd mention it just in case you happen to have some shared file you can drop it into anyway.

Comment: You are right, in my workspace I have some razor class libraries. When I apply the NoWarn it works but only temporarily... When using a razor file, the warnings appear then disappear. Then when I type they appear again, then disappear again! Really frustrating. In your estimation is this a config problem or bug?

Comment: It could be related to the same bug that makes editorconfig not work. Maybe try a clean build / rebuild / `dotnet build --no-incremental`

Comment: Sadly I've tried that and every combo imaginable. I have a suspicion different configs will benefit from different approaches. I'm sure your solution will work for some people. Also, I think the problem is less so on windows (understandably).